# How much overhead does ZFS have?

Tags: raid, freebsd, zfs

Adding a file system to a raw device of course takes up some overhead.

The question is how many percent does ZFS take?

And does overhead differ depending on the ZFS raid set?

**Update**

The purpose is to be able to be able to estimate usable disk space when designing a NAS.

Comment: How much overhead, compared to what?

Comment: There aren't very many use cases for data on raw devices, so a filesystem is almost necessary. If you have a specific case, you should mention it, like Oracle databases on raw devices vs Oracle databases on ZFS.

Comment: @ewwhite Updated the post. it is for designing NAS purposes.

Comment: Great question - not sure why its closed. Depending on your setup there is significant overhead - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tf4qx1aMJp8Lo_R6gpT689wTjHv6CGVElrPqTA0w_ZY/edit?pli=1#gid=930519344

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disk space lost in formatting a volume with the ZFS filesystem is negligible. If you set up mirrored vdevs or RAIDZ/RAIDZ2, then you lose the diskspace for the parity bits or mirrored data.

[This article](http://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/05/26/zfs-raid-levels/) walks you through the options.

Answer (score 4):

The most significant "overhead" will be the performance hit seen on very full pools:

> Keep pool space under 80% utilization to maintain pool performance. Currently, pool performance can degrade when a pool is very full and file systems are updated frequently, such as on a busy mail server. Full pools might cause a performance penalty, but no other issues. If the primary workload is immutable files (write once, never remove), then you can keep a pool in the 95-96% utilization range. Keep in mind that even with mostly static content in the 95-96% range, write, read, and resilvering performance might suffer.

From the [ZFS best practices guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170107215538/http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/ZFS_Best_Practices_Guide)

Some ZFS features like [ditto blocks](https://blogs.oracle.com/bill/entry/ditto_blocks_the_amazing_tape) or checksums may further increase redundancy and thus decrease the net capacity, although the exact impact will greatly depend on the configuration of your pool.